# Linear regression with constraint

Tags: regression, intercept, constraint

Can someone explain how to mathematically perform linear regression on some data while constraining the fit line to pass through the $(0,0)$ point?

Comment: Hi. I removed the contextual info about the module. I just want to understand how to make it wiyh pen and paper.

Comment: You are just suppressing the intercept. This is straightforward.

Comment: But won't that just translate the entire fit line to cross the origin ? I don't want to translate it, i want the slope of a line that starts from origin and fits the data as best as possible given the constraint. I think your sollution will yeld the slope of the unconstrained  fit line. Am I wrong ?

Comment: No, it isn't a vertical shift. If you use the equation I list at the linked thread you will get a different regression line. It may help to read my answer here: [What does the formula y ~ x + 0 in R actually calculate?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/174299/7290)

Comment: yes, i implemented that and it worked. thanks ! Any ideea how to compute standard error and standard deviation on them ? I am currently computing it using the standar error formula  but i am replacing the average Y with X*slope in sum( (Y-Yavg)^2 ). is that correct ?

Comment: I'm not sure. You could ask a new question for that.