# Interpretation of $R^2$ (coefficient of determination)

Tags: regression, correlation, model-evaluation, r-squared

I found two different and contradictory definitions / interpretations of $R2$. They cannot be true at the same time and I don't know how to tell which one is true.

1. $R^2$ is just a square of Pearson's correlation. Hence its value ranges between $[0, 1]$
2. $R^2$ is equal to
   $$1 - \dfrac{SSE}{SST}$$

and can be negative if the model is worse than random. For example - in Python's `sklearn` function `r2_score` can return a negative number.

Are those two different $R^2$s? Why are there two contradictory definitions? Can anyone explain it comprehensively?

Comment: Just because two formulas are not algebraically equivalent does not mean they are contradictory: one can be a special case of the other, for instance.  For 14 additional formulas for $R^2$ see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70969.  (Strictly speaking, you need to square those formulas for $\rho.$)

Comment: By contradiction I mean that one definition assumes $R2$ can be negative and the other that it ranges between 0 and 1

Comment: Neither definition makes such an assumption.  It merely *turns out* that, in some circumstances (where definition (1) is inapplicable), definition (2) can yield negative values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a simple setting where you fit a linear model, using ordinary least squares, and include an intercept, multiple definitions of $R^2$ give equal values.

1. In simple linear regression (just one slope and the intercept), Pearson correlation between the $x$ and $y$ values
2. Squared Pearson correlation between predicted and true $y$
3. Proportion of variance explained by the regression
4. Your second definition: a comparison of the square loss of your model to the square loss of a naïve model that always predicts the overall (pooled, marginal, unconditional) mean of $y$

(There are others, as discussed in [this link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70969) given in a comment by whuber.)

In simple settings, these give the same answer, so people use them interchangeably as the definition of $R^2$. However, in more complex settings, there are differences. I get into some of those differences [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/590199/how-to-motivate-the-definition-of-r2-in-sklearn-metrics-r2-score) and explain my support for the last of the four.

Answer (score 1):

If you fit both slope and intercept with linear regression, both your definitions will be true (and both give the same value of $R^2$).

If you only fit one of those (slope or intercept) and constrain the other to a fixed value (often the intercept is forced to equal 0), then the second definition is correct but the first definition will be wrong. And in this case, yes $R^2$ can be negative:
[What does negative R-squared mean?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/183265/what-does-negative-r-squared-mean)