# Is $R^2$ or RMSE more important for determining the success of a neural network regression?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, error

I have designed a neural network with two different choices of features.

Neither feature set stands out as one trains a neural network that scores higher $R^2$ coefficient on test data whereas the other feature set produces a neural network that scores the lower RMSE.

Which of $R^2$ and RMSE should be the deciding factor for which feature set is better?

Comment: What happens if you use both features sets?

Comment: They're basically the same thing (they both square differences to the mean such that outliers become somewhat important): $R^2_{ajd} = 1 - \frac{{RMSE}^2}{\sigma^2_y}$ See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32596/what-is-the-difference-between-coefficient-of-determination-and-mean-squared) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142248/difference-between-r-square-and-rmse-in-linear-regression)

Comment: @PatrickCoulombe watch out for doing $R^2$ out of sample. It makes no sense to me to compare to the variance of the training $y$, and the denominator is supposed to be the performance of the naïve model that always predicts the (training) $\bar y$, so it does not make sense to me to use the out-of-sample variance of $y$, either. See my comment to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are equivalent up to computational issues that arise from doing math on a computer.

$$R^2=1-\dfrac{SSResiduals}{SSTotal}$$

$$
RMSE = \sqrt{\dfrac{SSResiduals}{n}}
$$

Both are just functions of the sum of the squares residuals (“errors” in a mostly-acceptable-even-if-technically-incorrect machine learning slang).

Setting aside some issues that can arise from doing math on a computer, maximizing $R^2$ is the same as minimizing $RMSE$.

Comment: I would consider the out-of-sample $SSTotal$ to be equal to $\sum \big(    \hat y_i - \bar y _{\text{in sample}}      \big)^2$ for out-of-sample $\hat y_i$.